# Making a tab sleeted on an event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am making tabs using $("#tabs").tabs();

But I have a button on the page on clicking the button 3rd tab should be made as selected.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use active options of tab ...[doc here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)
try this

```
 $('#buttonID').click(function(){
     $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 2 }); //2 because it is zero-based index of the panel 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

After initializing the tabs using

```
$(".tabs").tabs();
```

you can set the active tab on button click using following code.

```
$(".tabs").tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
```